# Too many if branches in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am working on a project which was initially written in C. A few years ago, only some small changes were made, and source code was compiled under C++. Project is really huge and unfortunately it looks like this:

```
#define DEVICE_A 0
#define DEVICE_B 1
..
#define DEVICE_N 50

#define COMPANY_A 0
#define COMPANY_B 1
..
#define COMPANY_N 50

//and now the interesting part in other files:
if(giCompany == COMPANY_A || giCompany == COMPANY_B || 
giCompany != COMPANY_C && giDevice == DEVICE_A)
{
//... do something 
}
else
{
   if(giCompany == COMPANY_D)
   {
   // so something different
   }
}// and so on ...
```

What is the best way to deal with so many if - elses in C++? My example is really small, in real code is much more worse, there are so much if branches, that analyzing it takes ages ... Project is so big that I`m not going to touch existing code, but adding there such a mess as now I dont want to do. I started to use polymorphism (Interface for every *device*, and *devices* must implement their own methods instead of creating another if/else branches), and it looks much more better. But I want to ask, what is the common way do deal with such **if/else** problem in C++.

Comment: What is your problem? The sheer number of branches, or the complexity of the conditions? If each branch has it's destinct code, you won't get rid of them. It's not really a question of c++, but a question of software design. Try semantically grouping and separating the code. If it is the conditions you don't like, you could create a class encapsulating these.

Comment: `giCompany == !COMPANY_C` I have a sneaking suspicion this doesn't do what you think it does. Did you mean `giCompany != COMPANY_C`?

Comment: @Knowleech, both of them, it is difficult to maintain ...

Comment: @Borgleader, thanks you are right.

Comment: The example is too abstract to give you any specific advice. I understand you don't want to change the code, only the structure. (This is a reasonable approach!) If you can do anything about the branches, depends highly on what `//... do something` really does. As I said, best guess would be to try to semantically group the code and to try to refactor the conditions. I assume `giCompany` and `giDevice` are basically `int`s. Not much c++ there then. Refactoring into object might help, if you then can move code there. But it depends on your actual code.

Comment: Maybe you could simplify the logic by using [Karnaugh map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).  Think about this from a different angle:  Boolean arithmetic.

Comment: You could use tables with function pointers.  If the variable matches all the entries in the columns, execute the associated function pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Use switch-case:

```
switch(giCompany)
{
    case COMPANY_A:
    case COMPANY_B:
    {
        // Stuff
        break;
    }

    case COMPANY_C:
    {
        // Stuff
        break;
    }

    // ...
}
```

It will get a bit tricky if you do additional checks with a second variable (like `giDevice`)

Answer (score -2):

You could create a `std::vector` holding 2 functions: one for comparison (as if statement header), and one for action, if said comparison function returned `true`.

For example:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::function<bool()>, std::function<void()>>> operations =
    {
        {
        [=]
            {
            return giCompany == COMPANY_A || giCompany == COMPANY_B ||
                   giCompany != COMPANY_C && giDevice == DEVICE_A;
            },
        [&] { /*... do something */ }
        },
        {
        [=] {return giCompany == COMPANY_D;},
        [&] { /* do something different */ }
        },
    };

for (auto const& pair: operations)
    {
    if (pair.first ())
        {
        pair.second ();
        }
    }
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/EUFLPN).

---

Or, alternatively, if all of those `if-else` cases depend only on `giCompany`, and `giDevice`, you could pass them as an arguments to the functors:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::function<bool(int, int)>, std::function<void()>>> operations =
    {
        {
        [] (int company, int device)
            {
            return company == COMPANY_A || company == COMPANY_B ||
                   company != COMPANY_C && device == DEVICE_A;
            },
        [&] { /*... do something */ }
        },
        {
        [] (int company, int device) {return company == COMPANY_D;},
        [&] { /* do something different */ }
        },
    };

for (auto const& pair: operations)
    {
    if (pair.first (giCompany, giDevice))
        {
        pair.second ();
        }
    }
```

[Live Demo.](http://ideone.com/zNCb3J)

---

Since all of the functors are in a `vector` - they will be iterated, and evaluated in exactly the same order, as they would be in `if-else` tree. But, if you wanted to specify, that satisfying some condition, the iteration should stop, you could add an output argument:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::function<bool(int, int, bool&)>, std::function<void()>>> operations =
    {
        {
        [] (int company, int device, bool& stop)
            {
            stop = true;
            return company == COMPANY_A || company == COMPANY_B ||
                   company != COMPANY_C && device == DEVICE_A;
            },
        [&] { /*... do something */ }
        },
        {
        [] (int company, int device, bool& stop)
            {
            stop = false;
            return company == COMPANY_D;
            },
        [&] { /* do something different */ }
        },
    };

for (auto const& pair: operations)
    {
    bool stop = false;
    if (pair.first (giCompany, giDevice, stop))
        {
        pair.second ();
        }

    if (stop)
        {
        break;
        }
    }
```